# extjs ajax response with python bottle

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, extjs, bottle

i am new to web programming so please excuse my naive question, i tried searching on web but couldn't find answer to my basic question.

I am using extjs (for widgets and ajax) and python (using bottle) on server side.

here is my requirement.

I have extjs EditorGrid which has just one column (editable). on the index route (bottle route) i return json dictionary which is populated in this grid and shown, all well till this point, now I want to update value of this column and save updated value on the server side.

so i added another route on my python script, and ajax_reply as url to my ajax request on javascript (code below).

now my question is that how do i send a response to client, say for example i want to send a failure to client (i.e. updated was not successful on server and i want to send ajax response that update failed. i tried sending random stuff from my ajax_reply route but always success is called on client.

I am confused how to send a json response from ajax_repose function and then parse it again in my javascript success or failure function to act accordingly.

any help is much appriciated

```
@bottle.route('/ajax_reply', method='POST')
def update_column():
    return { 'success' : False }


var grid = new Ext.grid.EditorGridPanel({
                tbar: [{ text : 'Remove' }, {text : 'Add'}],
                ds: ds,
                frame:true,
                listeners: {
                  afteredit : function(e){
                        Ext.Ajax.request({
                        url : '/ajax_reply',
                        params : {
                               action: 'update',
                                id : e.record.id,
                                field: e.field,
                                value : e.value
                        },
                        success : function(resp, opt){
                           e.record.commit();
                           Ext.Msg.alert('SUCCESS', 'success...');
                        },
                        failure: function(resp, opt){
                           Ext.Msg.alert('ERROR', 'error...');
                           e.record.reject();
                        }
                  });
                }
                },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using `Ext.Ajax.request` you need to parse response yourself. Even if server can't update record but generated some kind of proper response

```
{ success: false, msg: 'Failed to save record' }
```

- this will still get to your `success` function. Because Ajax request itself was successful.

However if you're using grid and editors - I would recommend to look at different way of doing this - check documentation for remote stores, readers/writers etc.